# Flutter Error Message: "message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"AytUa8J8UWtBAqzv4-76M4c"

Tags: firebase, flutter, facebook, oauth, token

I would like to ask for help regarding this error. I am currently connecting facebook authentication in firebase to flutter. It's supposed to get data but it shows this error. Please check this out. thanks!

Here is my code.

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  var token;

  void _signInFacebook() async {
    var fbLogin = FacebookLogin();
    var result = await fbLogin.logIn(['email']);
    final graphResponse = await http.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name,email&access_token=${token}');
    print(graphResponse.body);
    if (result.status == FacebookLoginStatus.loggedIn) {
      FacebookAccessToken myToken = result.accessToken;
      AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken: myToken.token);
      var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    }
  }
```

Here is the error output.

```
I/flutter (17535): {"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"A64iqiLEAMXv67OEALVxSDE"}}
```

My dependencies:

```
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  firebase_core: ^0.4.4+3
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
```

Heres my build.gradle inside android

```
 minSdkVersion 23
 targetSdkVersion 29
```

Comment: Do you have facebook OAuth set up, or which key did you use?

Comment: Yes, I have made an app and the key came from it, I just followed some youtube tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your hashkey's in developer.facebook.com console.

Comment: Hi! I already added my hashkey. I run the command provided in developer.facebook.com >>> heres the command for mac (keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64) and I paster the key I got to the key hashes field

Comment: did you solve this problem